# Spring Boot version of embedded H2 database

Tags: maven, spring-boot, h2

Where can I find versions of embedded components in versions of Spring Boot e.g. embedded H2 database in Spring Boot 1.5.9-RELEASE.

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml. Switch the branch to the version you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can see all versions of sub components of Spring Boot in **Spring Boot Dependecies** module :

- [spring-boot-dependencies module pom.xml version 1.5.X](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml)

H2 version is `<h2.version>1.4.196</h2.version>`